# What file format should I export in to allow my .ai files to be opened in CorelDraw?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, file-conversion

My client's printer guy works in CorelDraw. I work in Illustrator. He needs to open the file in CorelDraw for printing.

In what format should I export the files so he can open those in Corel with no blurring issues?

All my files are vector only. No images used. Also, all of them are flat. No gradients or effects.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a job for .eps. Save your .ai file as .eps, and preferable choose  a somewhat older standard if Illustrator asks you for one.

.eps is made to be an interchangeable vector format. Especially if, as you say, no gradients or effects are included, it should open reliably and without error.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly work in Corel Draw, it all depends on what version of the Corel Draw he has.

**Modern Corel Draws:**

Can open all 3 files formats without problems(AI, EPS and PDF)

**Older Corel Draw:**

Can have problems opening all 3 files, most problems I have had with EPS. Best solution has been AI. One of my machines rocks a Corel Draw 12

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solves my problem. I have exported them as eps and pdf and forwarded it to him and it works!